# Could not find "application" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:application"}

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I recently updated an `ember-cli` project from `0.0.44` to `0.1.1` and all of the sudden my templates are not loading anymore, instead I get the following warnings on the console:

```
Could not find "application" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:application"}

Could not find "index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:index"}
```

The steps I took to update the project was just:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli
ember init
```

this is my router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('login');
  this.route('permission');
  this.route('user');
  this.route('room');
  this.route('room/new');
});

Router.reopen({
  notifyGoogleAnalytics: function() {
    return window.ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'page': this.get('url'),
      'title': this.get('url')
    });
  }.on('didTransition')
});

export default Router;
```

this is my `app.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;

var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  autoprefixer: {
    browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 1 version', 'android 4', 'ios 6']
  },
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver: Resolver
});

loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);

export default App;
```

any help?

Comment: @undefined its obviously because that thing isnt in that place

Comment: I tested with a fresh install from 0.0.44 and updated to 0.1.1 and it worked, so I'll just compare both and see what is out of place

Comment: what is the route application.index ? what directory are your templates in, can u provide all the information :)

Comment: I added my `route.js` file to the question, and my templates are in `app/templates/`, all named with .hbs, both `application.hbs` and `index.hbs` are there.

Comment: and I'm using `ember-simple-auth` as well

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should help:

```
npm cache clear
bower cache clean
rm -rf dist tmp bower_components node_modules
npm install
bower install
```

Comment: No idea why it works, but it saved me some time. It might be good idea to add it to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have to say that I tried @quaertym solution and it brought me a lot of problems. For other people it might help that this command:

```
rm -rf dist tmp bower_components node_modules
```

works great in OSX and Linux but as the documentation says https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#upgrading:

For Windows, use this command.

```
rd /s /q node_modules bower_components dist tmp
```